# How to display a custom block in a view twig file?

Tags: views, theming, blocks

I added a custom block in the header of a view, and I am trying to get it to display. The block contains social media icons and links.

If I want to add a custom text area, I can use this code -

`{{ view.header.area.options.content.value }}`

In my kint I see this for the block I added -

```
      "header" => array:3 [▼
          "entity_block" => array:12 [▼
            "id" => "entity_block"
            "table" => "views"
            "field" => "entity_block"
            "relationship" => "none"
            "group_type" => "group"
            "admin_label" => ""
            "empty" => true
            "tokenize" => false
            "target" => "socialicons"
            "view_mode" => "default"
            "bypass_access" => false
            "plugin_id" => "entity"
          ]
```

So I tried to do  `{{ view.header.entity_block }}` but I get an error -

`Exception: Object of type Drupal\views\Plugin\views\area\Entity cannot be printed. in Drupal\Core\Template\TwigExtension->escapeFilter() (line 425 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Template/TwigExtension.php).`

What can I do to display the block?

Answer (score 0):

You probably are confusing `{{ header }}` and `{{ view.header }}`.

The first prints the header section including the block:

*views-view.html.twig*

```
{{ header }}
```

The second one returns [ViewExecutable::$header](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21src%21ViewExecutable.php/property/ViewExecutable%3A%3Aheader/9.1.x), an array of handler plugins you have configured in the View. You can try to extract configured string values like in the first example but in case of a block entity you probably only find the block id and you have to load and render the block yourself. It would be much easier though to print `{{ header }}`.